# Awk Record separations and loops

Tags: awk, record, nested-loops, separator

Having some brainfart here. I have the following data in a file:

REMOVED TO AVOID CONFUSION

I’d like to be able to take data **BETWEEN** the separator (using date for example) and sum a column. On the top line, I have “date: NAME -delim : with the variable 2014 I can use.

Trying to say: “Look awk read this file, when you get to ‘sample data’ only go from those lines, and sum column 7”

```
awk -RS “2014” -F “:” ‘/sample data/'{ sum += $2 } END { print sum }' filename.txt
```

My guess is (without having to convert to bytes), that I can loop through, take MBs store them, tally them up, take GBs store those, and tally them as well. Any pointers?

Wishful thinking:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 2014 = ""} { if ($8 == “[0-9]GB") size = sum += $8"GB"; else … blah blah blah [0-9]MB}’
```

---- EDIT

I tried. Here is more or less the EXACT data I am working with (apologies but I am trying to minimize data exposure here):

**THIS IS THE CORRECT DATA SET WITH THE WORD SAMPLE MODIFIED FOR SANITIZATION**

```
Jul 2014: data disk -delim :

0:Sample_0:0:maps:online:0:Size 40GB15k:20.00GB:segment:3:location:::DA000000000000030:1:1:empty:1:no:0
1:Sample_1:0:maps:online:0:Size 40GB15k:20.00GB:segment:4:location:::DA000000000000031:1:1:empty:1:no:0
2:Sample_2:0:maps:online:0:Size 40GB15k:20.00GB:segment:5:location:::DA000000000000032:1:1:empty:1:no:0

Jul 2014: data network -delim :

0:Sample_3:0:maps:online:0:Size 60GB15k:10.00GB:segment:3:location:::DA000000000000030:1:1:empty:1:no:0
1:Sample_4:0:maps:online:0:Size 60GB15k:10.00GB:segment:4:location:::DA000000000000031:1:1:empty:1:no:0
2:Sample_5:0:maps:online:0:Size 60GB15k:10.00GB:segment:5:location:::DA000000000000032:1:1:empty:1:no:0
```

Did not work against this set. Also of importance is the following, if you notice, after the date, the variables differ. I have: disk, and data... I DO NOT need/want both instances summed. I'd like to be able to say: "look go find variable disk, and tally up all you see. DO NOT GO INTO data network

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a GNU awk extension, the [`match` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-match_0028_0029-function) to store the contents of the capturing parentheses

```
gawk -F: '
    $1 ~ /^[[:alpha:]]+ [[:digit:]]+$/ {
        if (sum) print sum
        printf "%s",$0
        sum=0
    } 
    /^[[:blank:]]*$/ {next} 
    {
        match($NF,/([[:digit:].]+)(|GB|TB)/, a)
        if      (a[2] == "GB") { sum += a[1]*1000 } 
        else if (a[2] == "TB") { sum += a[1]*1000*1000 } 
        else                   { sum += a[1] }
    } 
    END {print sum}
' << END

Jul 2014: sample data -delim :

0:Sample0:0:sampleX:online:0:2.00TB
1:Sample1:0:sampleX:online:0:2.00TB
2:Sample2:0:sampleX:online:0:2.00TB

Jul 2014: other data -delim :
0:Sample0:0:sampleX:online:0:3.00
1:Sample1:0:sampleX:online:0:4.00GB
2:Sample2:0:sampleX:online:0:5.00GB

Jul 2014: yet more data -delim :

0:Sample0:0:sampleX:online:0:9.00GB
1:Sample1:0:sampleX:online:0:10.00TB
2:Sample2:0:sampleX:online:0:11.00
END
```

```
Jul 2014: sample data -delim :6000000
Jul 2014: other data -delim :9003
Jul 2014: yet more data -delim :10009011
```

---

Given your new requirements:

```
gawk -F: '
    $1 ~ /^[[:alpha:]]+ [[:digit:]]+$/ {
        if (sum) print sum
        sum=0
        do_sum = ($2 ~ /disk/)
        if (do_sum) printf "%s", $0
    } 
    /^[[:blank:]]*$/ {next} 
    do_sum {
        match($8,/([[:digit:].]+)(|GB|TB)/, a)
        if      (a[2] == "GB") { sum += a[1]*1000 } 
        else if (a[2] == "TB") { sum += a[1]*1000*1000 } 
        else                   { sum += a[1] }
    } 
    END {if (do_sum) print sum}
'
```

For the sameple data, this prints

```
Jul 2014: data disk -delim :60000
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you invested in helping. I tried didn't work. Tried shifting $2 and $8 still wouldn't work.

Comment: hmm. It works for the sample data you posted. What's different in your real data?

Comment: Other than system names nothing. I will bring it over to another system via OSX, FreeBSD, and CentOS it didn't budge

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: '
  BEGIN {
    ksize = 1024
    sizes = "KMGT"
  }
  NF==7 {
    m = 1
    if (substr($7, length($7), 1) != "B")
      n = $7
    else {
      n = substr($7, 1, length($7) - 2)
      j = index(sizes, substr($7, length($7) - 1, 1))
      # if (j == 0) error!!!
      for (i = 1; i <= j; ++i)
        m *= ksize
    }
    sum += n * m
  }
  NF==3 {
    if (m) print sum
    printf "%s ", $0
    sum = 0
  }
  END {
    if (m) print sum
  }
' file
```

Testing `m` instead of `sum` allows zero sums. Once set, `m` is always non-zero. The test in the `END` condition handles an empty file properly.